# my scratch not work in Bootstrap3 modal

Tags: html

My scrath put one the page can work, but when I put into bootstrap3 modal ,it can't work,

I try to load modal first then load canvas, but can't work, 
I try to hidden overflow-y,when modal open, but can't work,

Ive tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

here is my code:

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
var Pencil = function(options) {
    this.options = {
        lineWidth: 60
    };
    this.init = function(canvas, ctx) {
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 256, 83);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "#c2c4c6");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "#c2c4c6");
    grd.addColorStop(0.5, "#ffffff");
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;

        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.canvasPos = $(this.canvas).offset();
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = this.options.fillStyle;
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.options.stroke_color;
        this.ctx.lineWidth = this.options.lineWidth;
        this.ctx.lineCap = "round";
        this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
        this.drawing = false;
        this.addCanvasEvents();
    };

    this.addCanvasEvents = function() {
        var c = $(this.canvas);
        c.on("mousedown", this, this.start);
        c.on("mousemove", this, this.stroke);
        c.on("mouseup", this, this.stop);
        this.bindMobile(c);
    };
    this.start = function(event) {

        var pen = event.data;
        var x = event.pageX - pen.canvasPos.left;
        var y = event.pageY - pen.canvasPos.top;


        pen.ctx.beginPath();
        pen.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        pen.drawing = true;
    };
    this.stroke = function(event) {
        var pen = event.data
        if (pen.drawing) {

            var x = event.pageX - pen.canvasPos.left;
            var y = event.pageY - pen.canvasPos.top;
            pen.ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            pen.ctx.stroke();
        }
    };

    this.stop = function(event) {
        var pen = event.data;
        pen.drawing = false;
        var imageData;
        var lineNum = 0,
            lineHei = 10,
            den = 10,
            pixel,
            drawnCounter = 0,
            sumCounter = 0;
        imageData = pen.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, pen.canvas.width, pen.canvas.height);
        for (h = 0; h < pen.canvas.height; h += lineHei) {
            for (w = 0; w < pen.canvas.width; w += den) {
                sumCounter++;
                pixel = imageData.data[((w + (h * pen.canvas.width)) * 4) - 1];
                if (pixel != 0 && pixel) {
                    drawnCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
        console.log((sumCounter - drawnCounter) / sumCounter);

        event.preventDefault();
        mousedown = false;

        // 跳中獎框1
        var num = 0;
        var datas = ctx1.getImageData(50, 25, w - 110, h - 50);
        for (var i = 0; i < datas.data.length; i++) {
            if (datas.data[i] == 0) {
                num++;
            };
        };

        if (num >= datas.data.length * 0.80) {
            $('#giftModal').modal('show');
        }





    };


    this.clear = function(canvas, ctx) {
        canvas.width = canvas.width;
        ctx.save();
        var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 256, 83);
        grd.addColorStop(0, "#c2c4c6");
        grd.addColorStop(1, "#c2c4c6");
        grd.addColorStop(0.5, "#ffffff");
        ctx.fillStyle = grd;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        ctx.restore();
        this.init(canvas, ctx);
    };

    this.bindMobile = function(obj) {
        obj.bind("touchstart touchmove touchend touchcancel", function() {
            var e = event.changedTouches,
                t = e[0],
                n = "";
            switch (event.type) {
                case "touchstart":
                    n = "mousedown";
                    break;
                case "touchmove":
                    n = "mousemove";
                    break;
                case "touchend":
                    n = "mouseup";
                    break;
                default:
                    return
            }
            var r = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
            r.initMouseEvent(n, true, true, window, 1, t.screenX, t.screenY, t.clientX, t.clientY, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            t.target.dispatchEvent(r);
            event.preventDefault()
        })
    };

};

var p1 = new Pencil();
p1.init(canvas1, ctx1);


// 設定獎品
document.getElementById('myCanvas1').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="gifttext"><h1>title1</h1><p>(可折现88888元）</p></div>');
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">      scratch    </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="cardbox" id="cardBox">
                    <div class="card" id="cardOne">
                        <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="256" height="83"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the pages on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help). It's better to add less code that clearly illustrates your problem. Also make clear what the exact problem is. Saying "It doesn't work" is never very helpful, apart from the fact that your code indeed does not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks @KIKOSoftware for remining^^

Comment: When I put the canvas scratch in the modal,  it can show fillstyle, but this code{ this.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; }  was fail, it can't show the effect .     I try to fixed until now, if have anyone can tell me any keyword,  Any comments will be much appreciated.